# MySQL Get data by previous quarter

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the last entry for the previous years quarter.

All I can access is year i.e `2021` and quarter i.e `1`

Here is the data in my database:

| id | name | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | April 2021 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 15 | March 2021 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 14 | February 2021 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 57 | November 2020 | 2020-11-01 | 2020-11-30 |
| 55 | October 2020 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-10-31 |
| 29 | September 2020 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-30 |
| 27 | July 2020 | 2020-07-01 | 2020-07-31 |
| 24 | April 2020 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-30 |
| 23 | March 2020 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-31 |
| 22 | February 2020 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-29 |
| 21 | January 2020 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31 |

Using the MySQL `quarter` function I can get it to print out the quarter as an integer in another column:

```
SET @given_year = 2021;
SET @given_quarter = 1;

SELECT 
     id, name, start, end, QUARTER(end) as "Q" 
FROM 
     submissions
```

| id | name | start | end | Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | April 2021 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 | 2 |
| 15 | March 2021 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-31 | 1 |
| 14 | February 2021 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 | 1 |
| 57 | November 2020 | 2020-11-01 | 2020-11-30 | 4 |
| 55 | October 2020 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-10-31 | 4 |
| 29 | September 2020 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-30 | 3 |
| 27 | July 2020 | 2020-07-01 | 2020-07-31 | 3 |
| 24 | April 2020 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-30 | 2 |
| 23 | March 2020 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-31 | 1 |
| 22 | February 2020 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-29 | 1 |
| 21 | January 2020 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-31 | 1 |

I tried using `WHERE` and `LIKE` but it is returning 0 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, name, start, end, QUARTER(end) as "Q" 
    FROM 
        submissions as s
) AS vs
WHERE
    vs.end
LIKE
    @given_year
AND
    vs.Q < @given_quarter
```

I also need to account for the possibility that there may be no rows this year and I need to find the previous year.

For example with these two rows, if I was passed the year `2021` and quarter `1` I would need to return November of the previous year and a different quarter.

| id | name | start | end | Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | February | 2021 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 57 | November | 2020 | 2020-11-01 | 2020-11-30 |

Comment: If you're using MySQL, why tag SQL Server? You have enough reputation to understand how tags work; please don't spam them. Thank you. Also, what does the question have to do with [tag:php]?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE @given_year` instead of `=` ?

Comment: @larnu - it was a suggested tag and reputation don't mean understanding of underlying frameworks or technology.

Comment: @B001ᛦ = because I am only given "2021" and the actual field contains "2021-02-01" etc..

Comment: *" it was a suggested tag"* So, again, what does your question have to do about [tag:php]? Just because it's a suggestion doesn't mean that it's related... Are you actually, therefore, looking for a solution in PHP not SQL? *"reputation don't mean understanding of underlying frameworks or technology. "* No, but it does mean an understanding of the site; 1,000 reputation means you should be familiar with how [so] and other sites in the SE community work, including what tags are used for. Tagging PHP means that you are asking a question *about* PHP, but I see no PHP in your question.

Comment: Tagging the wrong thing confuses the users you are asking for help from, @JamesG ... It means we don't know what technology you are *really* using or what technology you want a solution in. If you don't know what a tag means, then read the exert for it, or *don't* tag it. If it really is relevant, someone else will add it for you, but, again, don't tag spam. And also, please don't swear at me; this is a profession website, and we do ask that all users remain professional. Thank you.#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all the rows from the quarter in the data before a given quarter.  You can filter and use `dense_rank()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by year(start) desc, quarter(start) desc) as seqnum
      from submissions s
      where year(start) < @given_year or
            (year(start) = @given_year and quarter(start) < @given_quarter)
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

The above returns *all* rows from the previous quarter (which is what I thought you wanted).  If you want only one row:

```
select s.*
from submissions s
where year(start) < @given_year or
      (year(start) = @given_year and quarter(start) < @given_quarter)
order by start desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try that now.

Comment: I am unsure what `where seqnum = 1;` means and does. Also this returns 3 throws. I just need the previous 1 entry. For example with  the two rows at the bottom of my OP, if I was passed the year 2021 and quarter 1 I would need to return the row november. As it is the most previous one. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JamesG . . . I figured you wanted *all* rows from the previous quarter.  If you want only one, then the answer is simpler.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help.